# Fujitsu lifebook ah552 touch pad sensitivity and side scrolling problem

Tags: touchpad, fujitsu-siemens

Last week I bought a **Fujitsu Lifebook AH552** for just INR 29000/- it is the cheapest laptop available here (Kerala, India). With below configuration;

```
RAM : 4GB

Processor : Intel® Core™ i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 

Processor : Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
```

It comes without an operating system, so Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on their premises.

All the hardware components are worked perfectly as it made for Ubuntu, like

Brightness adjustment, wakeup from standby mode, sound, camera, microphone, bluetooth etc.

**But later i found that it had some issues with touchpad. Mainly it sensitivity was too low and because of this scrolling (both two finger and side scrolling) double click taping was not working smooth.**

**Touch Pad : AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint**

After some research on the Internet I found the solution and I am sharing my solution here for all of you have facing the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

Find the device name

```
xinput list
```

in my case it is
**AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint**

then find the current values for the device

```
xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" | grep -i finger
```

**In my case it was 12, 15, 0**

next we have to change the values as per below

**12, 12, 0**

for that we can use below command

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Finger" 12, 12, 0
```

Now the touch pad will be normal and also side scrolling should be working.

Finally we have to save the changes permanently, other wise this will not work after rebooting.

**Create a bash file**

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/fujitsu-lifebook-ah552-alps-touc-pad-settings.sh
```

the first line of the text should be this

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and after two line paste the command we previously used for changing the values.

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Finger" 12, 12, 0
```

save the file using shortcut ctrl+o, then exit ctrl+x

**make the file executable**

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/fujitsu-lifebook-ah552-alps-touc-pad-settings.sh
```

That's all! Do not forget to reboot the machine!

**Disable two finger scrolling on mouse setting to enable side scrolling.**